# Can I use react js for a long running application

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing an application, that will be running on screens 24/7, displaying different content. The question is: is it safe to use react js for this type of application? Does it care about memory leaks in long running applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will run perfectly if you handle it properly,and to day devices can handle more than we expect!.

so don't worry too much about the performance until you face a problem.